# Shifting from django 1.8 to 1.6.5

Tags: django

`localhost/admin` for my app has stopped working as I downgraded from django version 1.8 to version 1.6.5. What can I do to fix this problem.

Here is what the error says:

```
OperationalError at /admin/

no such column: django_content_type.name

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.12/admin/
Django Version:     1.6.5
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

no such column: django_content_type.name

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 451
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/home/ankit/www/library_site/public_html',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']

Server time:    Thu, 4 Jun 2015 12:01:52 +0000
```

Please suggest me a solution as I do not want to create my entire app from scratch again.

Comment: Why would you even do this?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to downgrade is to unapply all migrations except the first one (`manage.py migrate <app_label> 0001`) for all built-in apps. This will bring the model tables back to the state they were before 1.7, so that they will match the model code in 1.6.

You can either upgrade, follow these steps, and downgrade again, or you can manually add the `name` column back to the `django_content_type` table. However, I suspect there are quite a few other changes that would require manual work in the last case.

Comment: **thanks for a quick reply.

while migrating the app I get this error.**

raise exceptions.UnknownMigration(self, sys.exc_info())
south.exceptions.UnknownMigration: Migration 'app:0001_initial'
probably doesn't exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/migration/base.py",
line 313, in migration
migration = __import__(full_name, {}, {}, ['Migration'])
File "/home/ankit/www/library_site/public_html/app/migrations
0001_initial.py", line 4, in <module>
from django.db import models, migrations
ImportError: cannot import name migrations

Comment: @AnkitSahu because migrations come with version 1.7, and there is no migration operation in version 1.6.5! Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Django integrate `migrations` with version `1.7`. So you are trying to switch back from a `Django-Migrated` version to `South-Migrated` (if `south` is used)  or an `unmigrated` version.

Better you [read the version release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/) of `1.7` and `1.8` then try to figure your way out. Otherwise, you may need to backup your data, drop all tables and run `manage.py syncdb` (since `syncdb` is the model-database integrator in pre 1.7, not `manage.py makemigrations|migrate`) and then re-push your data back to your tables.